# How do I make a RCA to VGA converter?

Tags: digital-logic, design

In our area, all of us have a set-top box with RCA output (red, yellow, white) and I've a spare lcd monitor which has VGA input. I want to connect them to each other.

As RCA sends analog signals and VGA receives digital signals, can I make any kind of circuit so that it'll work?

I have basic knowledge of ICs but don't know which to use or even tried to Google with no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just search for a composite to vga or composite to video adapter. Amazon, or ...

Comment: "basic knowledge of ICs" will be nowhere near enough to roll your own composite-to-VGA converter.

Comment: @jonk Actually I want make component to VGA.

Comment: @replete I mean, I can work with it. If I got a Schematic of it.

Comment: @A_47 No one is going to post up a schematic as an answer, together with all the attending likely questions they'd get. Look up video decoder ICs or else get yourself a very fast ADC and a fast MCU and read up here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/734 , to start.

Comment: The red, yellow, and white connectors are composite, not component. And VGA is analog, not digital.

Answer (score 1):

This is an advanced topic with high frequency signals. Basic IC knowledge won't get you there here I'm afraid.

You basically have two options:
- Get a multimedia SOC, like in TV's.
- Get multimedia decoders, from [Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/hdmi-made-easy.html) for example.

Both require niche parts that might be hard to acquire and implement.

I suggest you find a reinventing the wheel.

Note: [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) has two sync lines that [component video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_video) has encoded into the signal. Although the signals are similar, functionality is not guaranteed.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/TV-RCA-Composite-S-Video-AV-In-To-PC-VGA-LCD-Out-Converter-Adapter-Box-US-/152321129537?hash=item23770bfc41:g:WfEAAOSwOVpXfm-A